# JQuery - clone element and change attributes for multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several elements like this:

```
  <div class="image_insert clearfix">
    <label for="userfile3">Image 3</label>
    <input type="file" name="userfile3" id="userfile3">
    <label for="slika_naziv_eng3">Image Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="slika_naziv_eng3" id="slika_naziv_eng3"/>
  </div>
```

And JS for cloning:

```
var img_add = $('.img_add');

img_add.on('click', function(){
  var img_ins = $('.image_insert'),
  i = img_ins.length,
  clon = img_ins.first().clone().attr({'class' : 'image_insert clearfix', 'name' : 'userfile' + i}).insertAfter(img_ins.last());
});
```

I need to change all attributes where there is a number. Every time new element is added, it needs to count number of elements and the new number will be number of elements + 1. How can I do this?

Comment: You already have `i` which is the number of elements, so you want to use `(i + 1)` when setting your attribute values.

Comment: where is the html img element for - $('.img_add'); ?

Comment: @wmitchell That seems entirely irrelevant to the question, personally.

Comment: It just makes it easier to throw together a sample soln in the likes of jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I've grabbed this from something similar id written in the past

```
$("#containerDiv").find("div").each(function(){
    lastVersionNumber = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace(/\D/g, "")/1;
});
newVersionNumber = lastVersionNumber + 1;

# build the new version HTML string
var sHTML = "<div name='mydiv'>";
sHTML += jQuery("#templateCode").html()
sHTML = sHTML.replace(/<input/i, "<input name='v"+newVersionNumber+"_name'");   
sHTML += "</div>";


$("#containerDiv").append(sHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: clon contains the new element, so, you need to find your element

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Clone Elements with Jquery by @MaoAiz + Sasha</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="img_add">New</button>
    <div class="image_insert clearfix">
        <label for="userfile1" class="img-label">Image 1</label>
        <input type="file" name="userfile1" id="userfile1">
        <label for="slika_naziv_eng1">Image Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="slika_naziv_eng1" id="slika_naziv_eng1"/>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var img_add = $('.img_add');

        img_add.on('click', function(){
          var img_ins = $('.image_insert'),
          i = img_ins.length + 1;
          clon = img_ins.first().clone().insertAfter(img_ins.last());
          // clon contains the new element, so, you need to find your element
          clon.find("input").first().attr({
            'name'  : 'userfile' + i,
            'id'    : 'userfile' + i
          });
          clon.find("input").last().attr({
            'name'  : 'slika_naziv_eng' + i,
            'id'    : 'slika_naziv_eng' + i
          });
          //plus:
          clon.find(".img-label").text("Image " + i)
          // view you cosole in Chrome Ctrl + Shift + j
          console.log("Elements: " + i)
        });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have a demo in github. https://github.com/MaoAiz/Formulario-Dinamico-JQuery